# Display message before creating excel in jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, excel, csv

I am creating a web app in my company. The user can click on a button and an csv is created with MySQL data.

So far so god.

In jquery, when the user clicks the button it redirect to:

```
document.location.href = '/SDR/SDRJSON.php?type=' + id;
```

On PHP the csv file is created:

I connect to the database and create a the csv file:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
{
    array_push($csv, $row);
}

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($csv as $row) {

    fputcsv($fp, $row, ';');
}

$FileName = 'PEW_'.$CountryCode;

fclose($fp);
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$FileName."'.csv");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
readfile('file.csv');
```

On the page where the button is, the user clicks there and the page starts waiting for the server and then the csv file starts downloading.

For small files is ok, because it is instantaneous. But for larger files it takes like 10 / 15 seconds. Is it possible to show a message while the page waits for the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't Think PHP can echo while the csv is being made ... What you could do is split the "Document Formation" and "Document Download" into two parts.

Let Ajax Make a query for the CSV to be made . And when that has been completed the PHP (Document Formation) will echo the Path of the File.

Then After that You can use document.location.href to Newly Created File.

I ll give the code

ajax-code

```
$('#sample-button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
 url : '/SDR/SDRJSON.php?type=' + id,
 success : function(data){
  if(data.url)
  {
   var urlToDownload = data.url;
   alert("File is ready for download");
   document.location.href = "http://www.domain.com/file/path/"+data.url;
   // Make sure data.url has the full path or append the data.url 
   // with some strings to make sure the full path is reflected 
   // into document.location.href ... 
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Something went wrong");
  }
 }
});
alert("CSV is being prepared Please wait... ");
});
```

documentFormation.php

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
{
    array_push($csv, $row);
}

$FileName = 'PEW_'.$CountryCode;
$fp = fopen($FileName, 'w');

foreach ($csv as $row) {

    fputcsv($fp, $row, ';');
}

fclose($fp);
$response = array();
$response['url'] = $FileName;

echo json_encode($response); // You can handle rest of the cases where to display errors (if you have any)
// Your DocumentFormation PHP Ends here. No need for header() or readFile.
```

If you dont want the file to stay on server , Edit the document href to This PHP passing 'path' as the parameter

`document.location.href = "documentDownload.php?path="+data.url;`

documentDownload.php

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
$filename = end(explode("/" , $path));
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
//Assuming $filename is like 'xyz.csv'
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$filename);
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
// Reading file contents
readfile('Relative Path to File'.$path);
// Deleting after Read
unlink('Relative Path to File'.$path); // To Delete right after reading
```

Comment: Thank you for the sugestion. But I am getting the "Something went wrong" alert. If I alert data instead the json is shown.

Comment: Might have been a php error .. I didn't initialize $response ..  try now ... You can also check the Ajax response using the "NETWORK" tab in the Web Developers Console of Any Browser

Comment: Can you be more specific on what 'data' has stored ? Try pasting the error here .. I can debug much better if I have the 'data''s content

Comment: The error I get on the alert is each cell from the csv file like test;test;test;test;test;test;test

Comment: Are you echo'ing the CSV in the PHP ? ... Just make sure the only thing you Echo is the File's Path and nothing else. Also additionally you don't have to set any headers or any such thing.

Comment: I am just echo the 'url'

Comment: Try var_dump($response);die(); ... You should get only one Array with 'url' => 'FileName.csv' ... Also I did some edit to the Filename .. it seems you were writing to file.csv and using another filename as PEW_FileName

Comment: I get: array(1){["url"] => string(32) "PEW_PT"}

Comment: Good. Make sure its PEW_PT.csv as that is the file you are writing to. Now After the json_encode there should be no code echoing or reading the file . Also There should be no header() set. I modified the JS part have a look

Comment: I don't understand I keep gettin null. When alert(data) on the else succeess ajax statemente. Should't I set ajax to json?

Comment: You are passing the ID to the documentFormation.php right? like '/SDR/SDRJSON.php?type=' + id this ? Try using the Network tab on your console to see what the PHP is returning.

Comment: Yes I pass the id in the data option if the json data: {type: id}

Comment: It was creating csv files on my server...?!?! What's happening is that a get null on the alert but the csv file is created on my server..

Comment: Yes, The idea behind it is to create the file on the server give the link to the user when the file is created. Okay so if ur passing type, Try opening the PHP in a new tab with specifying the TYPE. Do you get {'url' : 'PEW_PT.csv'}  It should exactly match this.

Comment: Getting Null means the echo json_encode never got executed. Make sure your If's are covered , try using die(); to stop the execution wherever you feel there is a bug. I am assuming this json_encode is in an 'if' statement that is never executed. Hence I think the output of the PHP is null. You 'll need to debug it step by step

Comment: Done! Is there any way to delete the file after? I did not use $response['url'] neither json_encode I echo the $FileName and the rest like you told me!

Comment: For that what you can do is u can redirect to another PHP and Initiate the download (using your headers) and then unlink() the file

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! When using dompdf to generate pdf can I do this as well?

Comment: Pretty Much any plugin can be used as long as it saves the File Separately and you can always pass a link to the JS when done! Then in the second php with the appropriate Content-Type and the fact that you can read the PDF file... will work. You will need to explore how to save a file using dompdf .. and the required headers for a pdf file download.